# Indexation of rich documents with solrnet

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, solr, solrnet

Can I index pdf documents with Solrnet ?

Is it possible to read content from a pdf and store it in in a field to indexation?

In fact, I would like store for example in a database a table who contains fields :

"Id","title", "Date","Path_Of_MyDocument". And so i want to index it with the content of my document(Most generally a rich text document).

Thank you for your responses and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

[Extracting request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) support is not yet complete in SolrNet ([issue here](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=79)). You may want to help implement it, or use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to call Solr directly, or use something like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to extract the text and then send it to Solr through SolrNet.